# How to add a table beside text on multiple lines in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Basically, I'm working on a resume and having a hard time getting the layout I want.

I have a title for my coursework section called "RECENT COURSEWORK", with each word on a separate line.  I want a table of my coursework organized *beside* it, rather than under the title.  How can this be accomplished in Word?

Answer (score 0):

> Create a table right below your text then add a **continuous section break** and divide the text and the table into columns.

Here's how to do that:

1. Type your text as you ordinarily would and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Create a table right below your text. The screen-shot below shows the sample text and tables.

   [image]
2. Insert a "**Continuous Section Break**" between your group of text and tables. To do that, place the text cursor immediately before the text you want to separate into a new section, go to **Page Layout** tab > **Breaks** > **Continuous**.

   [image]
3. You now have separated your groups of text and table. Show the non-printing characters to see the inserted section breaks by clicking on **Home** tab > **Paragraph** group > **Show/Hide** or simple press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>.

   [image]

   [image]
4. Select a group of text and table and divide it into two columns by clicking on **Page Layout** tab > **Columns** > **More Columns...**

   [image]
5. In the **Columns** dialog box, select either **Two**, **Left** or **Right** and adjust the column widths and distance between columns, then click on **OK**.

   [image]
6. Your text and table will now be in separate columns. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as necessary to move the table to the second column.

   [image]
7. Hide the non-printing characters by clicking on the **Show/Hide** button. You now have created a table to the right of your text. Output should look like below.

   [image]